# Exception in "Hello World" program on a clean Python install

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I installed python on Windows 7, but it didn't work as well as it worked on Linux Ubuntu. I wrote a simple program and it still gives me an error:

```
>>>print("HelloWorld")
'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character
```

[image: Python error]

Comment: What text editor did you use to write the program? Maybe it snuck in some invisible characters that make Python barf.

Comment: Could you post the result of `open(spam.py, 'b').read()`?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely you have some header which is not displayed by your text editor. Like [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for example. Check your editor settings to get rid of this header.

Comment: Thank you but when I try to write the command on Python Shell and not to a New Window it works well . So ?

Comment: @general656 It you type the command directly into python shell there is no BOM (ore any other header) used. BOM is used to define bytes order for multibytes character sets. That's a *file* property (actually first bytes of a file).